# Display validation error in tabs using laravel

Tags: php, tabs, laravel-5, laravel-validation

In my view I've 3 tabs where different types of data are displayed. In my 3'rd tab i post some data where i use laravel validation. My problem is the validation errors are displayed in my first tab. What should i do to display the errors in the 3'rd tab.

my controller

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), Rules::Event($request));
        if ($validator->fails()) {
           return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
```

view page

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Upcoming Events</a></li>
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Popular Events</a></li>
          <li ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Post an Event and sell ticket</a></li>
        </ul>

<div class="tab-content">

 <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
................
</div>

 <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
..............
</div>

 <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">

<div class="event_tab_holder"> 


                @if (count($errors) > 0)
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h5><strong>{{ t('Oops ! An error has occurred. Please correct the red fields in the form') }}</strong></h5>
                            <ul class="list list-check">
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endif
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to implement this? Please help me,Waiting for a response......

Answer (score 2):

you can try this one:

add `error` class to `li`

```
<li class='error'>{{ $error }}</li>
```

then use this script:

```
   if ($(".tab-content").find('.error').text()) {
    $.each($(".tab-content").find('.error'), function (index, value) {
        if ($(this).text()) {
            $(".tab-content").children('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
            $(this).closest('.tab-pane').addClass('active');
            $(".nav-tabs").children('li').removeClass('active');
            var id = $(this).closest('.tab-pane').attr('id');
            $.each($(".nav-tabs").children('li'), function (i, a) {
                if (('#' + id) == $(this).children('a').attr('href'))
                    $(this).addClass('active');
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i have used this code for the same issue and its working very well. do one thing put class for li `<li class='error'>{{ $error }}</li>`

Comment: when i implement this code the errors are displayed in the <li>. I want the error to be displayed in the div where the contents are placed. and the class of <li> to be active.